# isn't it very hard to maintain a node.js application that is using many third party packages?

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I have a general question. If any node application is using many (>20) third party npm packages or git repos, wouldn't it be very hard to maintain or upgrade it? Basically, I want to understand how do we maintain such big projects?

Thanks,
JVM

Answer (score 0):

The question is very general.

We have used https://greenkeeper.io/ with great success in a repository with at least 50 dependencies. It all depends on how frequently the project will be worked on. If it's being worked on every day. Greenkeeper is great for keeping deps up to date.

If the project only needs updates very occasionally your best bet is probably to freeze all dependencies and transitive-dependencies with some lock file mechanism. https://yarnpkg.com has this built in. That way all reinstalls are deterministic as they use frozen versions of all dependencies. In this model dedicated maintenance day is required every now and then to bump the frozen dependencies.